# As a Federated AWS user where can I see the roles/permissions I am assigned?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

At the place where I work, I have to sign-in via SSO to access the AWS dashboard.

How do I see which roles/permissions my user account has?

Every-time I fail to access a resource or perform an action, I am having to ask my team mate if he can perform that action. If he is able to do it, then I infer that my account is lacking a permission.

Comment: once you're logged in, you'll have assumed a role into that account.  You can see which role you assumed in the dropdown on the top-right.  Then you can look up that role in IAM, assuming you have permissions to do so, and introspect the policies.

Comment: Chances are that you don't have IAM permissions so you would not be able to retrieve that information. However, why ask the internet? Why not ask the admin at your location that set this up?